# PDE Solving in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'd like to ask how I might go about solving this equation:

## $\frac{\partial Ci}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial (r^2 Ci)}{\partial r} = D\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\frac{\partial Ci}{\partial r})$

as suggested a simplification

## $\frac{\partial Ci}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{r}2Ci +\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial Ci}{\partial r} = D(\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial Ci}{\partial r} +\frac{\partial^2 Ci}{\partial r^2})$

$r = 0, t = 0 \rightarrow Ci = 0$
$r = 1, t = 0 \rightarrow Ci = 0$

I am fairly new to Mathematica and I don't really know how to go about this; I've also tried the steps outlined in this post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14201/numerically-solving-an-inhomogeneous-partial-differential-equation) but while I understood what to do I get recursion limit reached errors (using the code provided).

Could you please help me out on how to solve this equation?

a partial and first attempt on solving this taking in account the notes of the posted link is the following:

```
Clear[y];
f1[r_ /; r > 0] := 1;
f1[r_ /; r == 0] := 2;
f2[r_ /; r > 0] := 1/r^2;
f2[r_ /; r == 0] := 0;
f3[r_ /; r > 0] := 1/r;
f3[r_ /; r == 0] := 0;

eqns = {  
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][y][t, r, z] +  
  f3[r]*2*y[t, r, z] +
  f2*Derivative[0, 1, 0][y][t, r, z] -
  2*f3[r]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][y][t, r, z] -
  Derivative[0, 2, 0][y][t, r, z] == Derivative[1, 0, 0][y][t, r, z],
  y[t, 0, z] == 0,
  y[t, r, 0] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][y][t, 0, z] == 0,
  Derivative[0, 0, 1][y][t, r, 0] == 0,
  y[0, r, z] == (1 - r^2)*(1 - z^2)}

 $RecursionLimit = 1536

 y[t_, r_, z_] = 
     y[t, r, z] /. 
          First[NDSolve[eqns, y[t, r, z], {t, 0, 1}, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
          Method -> {"MethodOfLines", Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
          "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, 
          "ScaleFactor" -> 1}}]];
```

This gives me a lot of errors but the first one is the following:

[image: partial error output]

Comment: You do not provide any code.

Comment: I said that I tried the code (tailored for my equation) that was supplied in the post I linked, do you need a more?

Comment: Yes, at least the equation.

Comment: Well, I have a problem with that I don't know how to type in the second partial; that is I don' know how to write the $\frac{\partial r^2Ci}{\partial r}$. This has both r and Ci inside which I don't how to type them.

Comment: You mean D[ r^2 Ci[r,t], r] ? (I suppose Ci is a function of r and t). By the way, Ci and D are not the best names for variables in Mathematica. I'd switch to lowercase if I were you. At least for D.

Comment: Having hard time reading your PDE equation. What is $\frac{\partial (r^2 Ci)}{\partial r}$ ? Since $r$ is an independent variable. and not dependent, why not write it as $2 r Ci + r^2 \frac{\partial Ci}{\partial r}$ ? And it will be more clear to use one letter for $Ci$ and removing this un-needed $i$ in there. Also, it help to have a link to the PDE if it is a known one.

Comment: I think it is a not known one; I've found it in an old paper. You are correct $Ci$ is dependent at $r$ and $t$; you could say that $Ci[t,r]$. As for $D$ it is a variable constant.

Comment: Despite Nasser has kindly given an answer to this question, I'd like to cast my -1 because 1. The two equations written with LaTeX is inconsistent i.e. the 2nd one actually isn't the simplified form of the 1st one. 2. The i.c. (b.c.?) in LaTeX form is confusing. 3. The equation in the code is completely different from the one written in LaTeX, where does the z come from? 4. The link of the old paper (mentioned in the comment above) isn't given so it's impossible to check if the equation is copied correctly. (I'm almost sure there's something wrong, though. )

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using the method of characteristics. But the conditions as given above will cause a problem at $r=0$. There is no Cauchy data to use. So I kept the solution in terms of the constants of integrations.

Let $u\left(  t,r\right)  $ be the solution

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial\left(
r^{2}u\right)  }{\partial r} &  =D\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial\left(
r^{2}u\right)  }{\partial r}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\left(  2ru+r^{2}\frac{\partial
u}{\partial r}\right)   &  =D\frac{1}{r^{2}}\left(  2ru+r^{2}\frac{\partial
u}{\partial r}\right)  \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\left(  2\frac{u}{r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial
r}\right)   &  =D\left(  2\frac{u}{r}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)  \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\left(  1-D\right)
&  =-2\frac{u}{r}\left(  1-D\right)
\end{align*}

Let $1-D=k$, hence

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+k\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}  & =-2k\frac
{u}{r}\\
\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}  &
=-2\frac{u}{r}
\end{align*}

To find the solution using the characteristics method, we write the
above in the standard form

$$
\frac{dt}{k^{-1}}=\frac{dr}{1}=\frac{du}{-2\frac{u}{r}}%
$$

Hence $dt=\frac{dr}{k}$ or $t=\frac{r}{k}+r_{0}$ or
$$
r_{0}=t-\frac{r}{k}
$$
Also, $\frac{du}{-2\frac{u}{r}}=dt$ or $\frac{du}{u}=-\frac{2}{r}dt$, hence
$\ln u=-\frac{2}{r}t+c_{2}$, or $u=Ae^{-\frac{2t}{r}}$.

At $t=0$, to satisfy initial conditions at $r_{0}$, then $u\left(
0,r_{0}\right)  =f\left(  r_{0}\right)  =A$. So the solution is
$$
u\left(  t,r\right)  =A\left(  t-\frac{r}{k}\right)  e^{-\frac{2kt}{r}}%
$$

Mathematica gives this btw:

```
  ClearAll[u, r, t, k];
  ode = D[u[r, t], t] + k D[u[r, t], r] + 2 k u[r, t]/r
  sol = u[r, t] /. First@DSolve[ode == 0, u[r, t], {r, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Again, I think the initial conditions given are not correct.

see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/SolveAPartialDifferentialEquation.html

for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nasser; if that is the case then you can assume since we cannot solve for all $D$ that $D$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ for that $k=\frac{1}{2}$. That way I get an answer but I don't think it is a correct one.

Also the limits can be $0 \rightarrow 1$ and if I do 
    (sol /. {r -> 1, t -> 1}) == 0 
I get an answer but that is a differential equation as well.

Comment: This is a first order linear PDE, but it is inhomogeneous PDE. But you can still solve it analytically using separation of variables. You need to use eigenfunction expansion method.

Comment: can you give me an example? The post I read had a similar equation for solving but I can't figure how to adapt my code to that code.

Comment: @jtimz You can actually use the method of characteristics also to solve it? start by writing $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dr}{k}=\frac{du}{-2k\frac{u}{r}}$ and then $\frac{dr}{dt}=k$ or $r=tk+c_{1}$ or $r-tk=c_{1}$ and $\frac{du}{dt}=-2k\frac{u}{r}$ or $\frac{du}{u}=-2\frac{k}{r}dt$, hence $\ln
u=-2\frac{k}{r}t+c_{2}$, hence $u=c_{2}e^{-2\frac{k}{r}t}$
So the the solution is function
$f\left(  r-tk,ue^{2\frac{k}{r}t}\right)$. I just forgot more of the details now. Need to look it more...separation of variables will also work....

Comment: thanks will look it a bit more and will let you know! Thanks a ton!