# (NDSolve) Non-linear 2nd order ODE, regular singular point (looking for good methods for this problem)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am solving this set of non-linear 2nd order ODE by NDSolve,
$$r^2\frac{d^2f}{dr^2} = 2f(1-f)(1-2f)+\frac{r^2}{4}h^2(f-1)$$
$$\frac{d}{dr}\left[r^2\frac{dh}{dr} \right]=2h(1-f)^2+\lambda r^2(h^2-1)h$$
$$ f(0)=h(0)=0, \quad f(\infty)=h(\infty)=1$$

From the series solution, I also know the behavior at $r\approx0$,
$$ f\approx \alpha r^2, \quad h\approx \beta r$$ 
Therefore the singularity at $r=0$ is a regular singular point.

I tried using NDSolve,

```
\[Lambda] = 625/2048;
eqn = {r^2*f''[r] == 
2 f[r] (1 - f[r]) (1 - 2 f[r]) - r^2/4 (h[r])^2 (1 - f[r]), 
D[r^2*h'[r], r] == 2 h[r] (1 - f[r])^2 + \[Lambda]*r^2 (h[r]^2 - 1) h[r]};
bc = {f[0.000001] == 0, f[20] == 1, h[0.000001] == 0, h[20] == 1};
sol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, {h, f}, {r, 0.000001, 20}]
```

However, it doesn't solve it says *At r =...., step size is effectively zero;
singularity or stiff system suspected.*

I also tried,

```
NDSolve[{eqn, bc} /. {f -> (#^2 g[#] &), h -> (# j[#] &)}, {g, j}, {r, r1, r2}]
```

with boundary condition at r1 and r2. Still it doesn't give me the solution.

I guess there are some subtleties about non-linear ODEs. Since it is non-linear, the solution is highly sensitive to boundary conditions. Unless I set the exact boundary condition, it won't give me the right answer. However, the ODE above has a regular singular singular point at $r=0$, which I don't know how to impose the exact boundary condition at $r=0$ in mathematica. It stops calculation immediately if I set the boundary condition at $r=0$.

I am looking for help from you guys, especially those had the same problem before. My sincere thank for your help!

***Do you know if the method of relaxation help in this case?***

**Update: The method of relaxation works well for this type of problem, however it seems that Mathematica does not implement this for NDSolve algorithm.**

Comment: `at r=0 is a regular singular point.` I though the classification of ordinary, regular, and not regular singular points applies to linear ODE's. But what you have is non-linear ODE's.  I could be wrong, but I remember something like this from a class.

Comment: you are right but how do you describe that in nonlinear ODEs?

Comment: @Nasser The classification of ordinary/regular/singular point can be applied to nonlinear ODEs by investigating the asymptotic behavior of their solution in the vicinity of that point.

Answer (score 6):

Using the final substitution given in the Question with the addition of `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` produces a solution for `r2` as large as `7.4`, after which even `"StiffnessSwitching"` is insufficient to treat the equations at `f` and `h` very near `1`.

```
λ = 625/2048;
r1 = 10^-6; r2 = 7.4;
eqn = {r^2*D[D[f[r], r], r] == 
        2 f[r] (1 - f[r]) (1 - 2 f[r]) - r^2/4 (h[r])^2 (1 - f[r]), 
       D[r^2*D[h[r], r], r] == 
        2 h[r] (1 - f[r])^2 + λ*r^2 (h[r]^2 - 1) h[r]};
bc = {f[r1] == 0, f[r2] == 1, h[r1] == 0, h[r2] == 1}; 
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, bc} /. {f -> (#^2 g[#] &), h -> (# j[#] &)}, {g, j}, 
  {r, r1, r2}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];
Plot[{r^2 sol[[1]][r], r sol[[2]][r]}, {r, r1, r2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without `"StiffnessSwitching"`, integration fails at `r2` of about `5.22`.

**Addendum - (Corrected) Asymptotic Solution**

In the limit of large `r`, the first term on the right side of each equation is small compared to the other terms and can be dropped;

```
{r^2*D[D[f[r], r], r] == - r^2/4 (h[r])^2 (1 - f[r]), 
 D[r^2*D[h[r], r], r] == λ*r^2 (h[r]^2 - 1) h[r]};
```

Moreover, since `f` and `h` approach `1` for large `r`, the equations can be linearized about `1` to yield

```
{r^2*D[D[f[r], r], r] == r^2/4 (f[r] - 1), 
 D[r^2*D[h[r], r], r] == 2 λ*r^2 (h[r] - 1)};
```

These equations are uncoupled and can be solved analytically (or with `DSolve`).

```
fasym = 1 - a Exp[-r/2];
hasym = 1 - b Exp[-Sqrt[2 λ] r]/r
```

with `a` and `b` constants.  (I thank mastrok for pointing out in a Comment below that I had mistakenly assumed `a = b = 1` in the first version of this addendum.)  These asymptotic expressions can be used to improve the boundary conditions for `NDSolve`.  To do so, set

```
f[r2] - 1 == - a Exp[-r2/2];
f'[r2] == a Exp[-r2/2]/2;
```

`a` can be eliminated between these two equations to yield `2 f'[r2] + f[r2] == 1`.  A similar but more complicated expression is obtained for `h`.  In all,

```
bc = {f[r1] == 0, 2 f'[r2] + f[r2] == 1, h[r1] == 0, 
      r2 h'[r2] + h[r2] (Sqrt[2 λ] r2 + 1) == 1 + Sqrt[2 λ] r2};
```

Although the improved boundary conditions do not increase the range over which `NDSolve` produces meaningful results (in fact, it reduces the upper bound from `7.44` to `6.99`), it does moderately improve the overall results.  The figure below shows the numerical (solid) and asymptotic (dashed) curves superimposed.

```
Show[Plot[{r^2 sol[[1]][r], r sol[[2]][r]}, {r, r1, r2}],
     Plot[{1 + a Exp[-r/2], 1 + b Exp[-r Sqrt[2 λ]]/r}, {r, 5, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> Dashed], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The excellent overlap between the small and large `r` solutions indicates that the asymptotic solutions are quite accurate for `r` as small as `5`. Quantitatively, `a` and `b` are equal to `1.36` and `3.37` for `r2 = 6.99` and `1.41` and `3.29` for `r2 = 6.00`.

Comment: useful answer. one thing I don't get is, why are the constants in the asymptotes 1? I got 2 constants in these expressions,
    f = 1 - A*Exp[-r/2];
    h = 1 - B*Exp[-Sqrt[2 λ] r]/r

Comment: Also, the solution is extremely sentive to r1 and r2. Changing them by a bit will totally change the numerical solution. That's the annoying part for me. Is there any way to impose better boundary condition ?

Comment: @mastrok  I have not found the results to be sensitive to `r1`, and only modestly sensitive to `r2` if `NDSolve` succeeds in satisfying the boundary conditions accurately at `r2`.  More to follow on your first comment.

Comment: Do you know if there is other better method for solving these ODEs ? Like relaxation, I just heard about this method but not sure about the details

Comment: The relaxation method applied to nonlinear ODEs is described [here](https://www.math.ohiou.edu/courses/math3600/lecture34.pdf) and elsewhere on the web.  To use it, you would need to discretize your equations using FEM, as described in the Mathematica [FEM Users Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html).  Conceptually, the relaxation method can be thought of as converting the ODEs to first order PDEs in time, the solutions of which (one hopes) relax to a steady state that is the solution to the original ODEs.