# What causes the warning "The dependent variable in the boundary condition needs to be linear" when using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method

V 12.1.1 on windows 10

Why the following works

```
ClearAll[u, x, y];
pde  = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}];
bc   = {u[0, y] == 1, u[1, y] == 0};

sol  = NDSolve[{pde == NeumannValue[0, y == 0] + NeumannValue[0, y == 1], bc},
          u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "u"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

ps. I know `NeumannValue[0, y == 0]` above are not needed in this example, since by default they are zero. So the above could also be written as

```
sol = NDSolve[{pde == 0, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

But here is the problem.

Now I just changed `NeumannValue[0, y == 0]` to use standard `Derivative` instead, and `NDSolve` gives now a warning

```
ClearAll[u, x, y];
pde = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0;
bc  = {u[0, y] == 1, u[1, y] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0, 
          Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 1] == 0};

sol = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

[image]

But bc is not nonlinear. I have not even changed it. So why does the warning says it is?

To show these boundary conditions are valid, changed `NDSolve` to `DSolve` and it gave same solution as the first one above using `NeumannValue`

```
ClearAll[u,x,y];
pde = Laplacian[u[x,y],{x,y}]==0;
bc  = {u[0,y]==1,u[1,y]==0,Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]==0,Derivative[0,1][u][x,1]==0};

sol = DSolve[{pde,bc},u[x,y],{x,y}];
sol = Simplify[Activate[sol]]

Plot3D[u[x,y]/.sol,{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[u[x, y] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Can't one use `Derivative` now with `NDSolve` and have to use `NeumannValue`? And why it says dependent variable  in the boundary condition is not linear when it is?

ps. I tested this on 12 and 11.3 and they give same warning. I do not have earlier versions of Mathematica to test on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this issue has raised up in a number of posts, but surprisingly I can't find a duplicate. Seems that it's never asked in a clear enough way as in your question. In short, When `FiniteElement` is used for spatial discretization, one cannot express Neumann and Robin b.c. with `Derivative`, and have to use `NeumannValue`, at least now. You might remember the discussion here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172972/how-to-use-finite-elements-to-solve-an-initial-value-ode-with-ndsolve/172998#comment454396_172998

Comment: @xzczd thanks. I remember that question. But that was about using finite elements to solve  time dependent ode. I am here not even asking to use Finite elements in the example where the error was generated. I see you said `When "FiniteElement" is chosen`. So what what is the bottom line here? One can not use `Derivative` at all as BC. with `NDSolve` Since when this started? May be if you know, you can make an answer giving the rules of thumb to follow, as I am now confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let me extend my comment to an answer. You're solving Laplace equation, for which the new-in-*v10* `FiniteElement` is the only available method in `NDSolve` at the moment. For more info about when `FiniteElement` will be automatically chosen, check the following post:

[PDEs : automatic method choice : TensorProductGrid or FiniteElement?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/1871)

When `FiniteElement` is used for spatial discretization, one cannot express b.c. (include but not limited to Neumann b.c. and Robin b.c. ) with `Derivative`, and has to use `NeumannValue`, at least now. [I tried to convince user21 to implement the automatic transform from `Derivative` to `NeumannValue` for regular domain (rectangle, disk, cube, ball, etc.) in [comments under this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172998/1871), but failed. ]

BTW, the following are examples solving Laplace equation in pre-*v10* days:

[Numerically solving an inhomogeneous partial differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14201/1871)

[Optimizing a Numerical Laplace Equation Solver](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23601/1871)

---

I create a function [`allowfemdbc`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268449/1871) to facilitate setting Neumann/Robin b.c. when `FiniteElement` is chosen.

Comment: Ok, thanks. this makes it more clear. I wonder why can't NDSolve, **internally** modify the `Derivative` to `NeumannValue`? This way, same code used for `DSolve` can be used with `NDSolve` without having to change the `bc`.   This also assumes the user has to know that FEM will be used to solve  the equations they are working on. Not every one knows these internal things by just looking at the equations and know what solver Mathematica choose to use in order to change the BC to make it happy.

Comment: @Nasser You may take part in the discussion in 2nd link :) .

Answer (score 2):

You assume that `NeumannValue` and `Derivative` are interchangeable; they are generally not. This is explained in more detail in the section [The Relation between NeumannValue and Boundary Derivatives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1529668360) in the [Finite Element Method User Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html). Also the `NeumannValue` ref page has detailed information what it models.

Let's look at the message: The message states that `Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]` needs to be linear when used in `DirichletConditon`:

[image]

This means that NDSolve parsed your input `Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]` as a `DirichletCondition` and it tells you that it needs to be linear. You get the same message when you use

```
bc = {u[0, y] == 1, u[1, y] == 0, Sin[u[x, 0]] == 0,...}
```

Things like `f[u[x,y]==...` where f is not some sort of `Indentity` function are nonlinear and that includes Derivative[0,1][u].

Also, note that the message tag is `fembdnl`. So `NDSolve` choose to use the finite element method (all messages coming from the FEM subsystem start with fem).

What confuses me is that you show a screenshot of the message ref page but it seems you have not read the page completely. Because there is an example on that page that shows exactly this issue. Let me quote that (ref/message/NDSolve/fembdnl#506322725):

---

For the finite element, spatial discretization derivatives need to be modeled with NeumannValue:

```
NDSolve[{Laplacian[c[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - c[x, y, z] == 0, 
  c[x, y, 0] == 1, Derivative[0, 0, 1][c][x, y, 1] == c[x, y, 1], 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][c][x, 1, z] == c[x, 1, z], 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][1, y, z] == c[1, y, z], 
  Derivative[0, 1, 0][c][x, 0, z] == c[x, 0, z], 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][c][0, y, z] == c[0, y, z]}, c, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0,
   1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The solution is to use NeumannValue:

```
NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[c[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - c[x, y, z] == 
   NeumannValue[c[x, y, z], 
    z == 1 || y == 1 || x == 1 || y == 0 || x == 0], 
  DirichletCondition[c[x, y, z] == 1, z == 0]}, c, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 
  1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

---

I have moved this example further up - now it's the second example. I also added links to the relation between `Derivative` and `NeumannValue` section and added a link to the section: [What Triggers the Use of the Finite Element Method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1993509248)

The fact that you can replace `NDSolve` with `DSolve` in your example is a coincidence and does not hold generally when making use of NeumannValue. Looking at it from the other side: You can not use your first example (with `NeumannValue`) and use DSolve on it either.

So the answer to your question:

> Can't one use `Derivative` now with `NDSolve` and have to use `NeumannValue`

You can not use `Derivative` as **a boundary condition** with the finite element method. This never worked so it is nothing that changed "now".

Concerning the comments: The automatic conversion of `Derivative` to `NeumannValue` is far from trivial. It's not impossible but seen that this has not been requested as a [Future enhancements for the finite element method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199163/future-enhancements-for-the-finite-element-method) I am not sure it has a high priority.

Comment: Thanks for comments. But my main point is that I was not calling "finite elements" to solve the PDE. I was just calling `NDSolve`. A user should not have to know which specific solver is going to be used internally and adjust call parameters in order to satisfy the format needed for that specific solver.  So when you say `You can not use Derivative as a boundary condition with the finite element method.` my answer is, then NDSolve error message should have been exactly this. At least it would be more clear to users what the cause of the error is, instead of giving message about not linear BC.

Comment: If you like, here is an error message that I think would be much more clear to the users when this happens: `NDSolve has selected to use Finite Elements method as the solution method. However FEM do not currently support Derivative as a boundary condition. Please correct and try again`  With such an error message, it is much more clear what is going on.

Comment: @Nasser, at that point in the code, I have no way of knowing if the method was chosen automatically or given. I simply do not have access to that information at the point when the message is issued. I'll have a look what can be done  - but this is going to anything else but trivial as suggest.

Comment: @Nasser, the best that could be done is something like: `Derivative can not be used as a boundary condition for the finite element method.`

Comment: Yes, that messge would be much much better error message to the user than the current one. It is more clear and to the point on what the cause of the problem is, instead of the current one, which is long way around about the real cause. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser, version 12.2 will have a better message.