# How to find the analytical or numerical solution of a system of partial differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method, solidmechanics

I am trying to use mathematica to solve a system of second-order partial differential equations, but I have been unable to solve it. The code of mathematica is as follows:

```
l = 26
b = 18
μ = 0.2
β = 0.0436
α = 10^(-5)
t = 20
func3 = {Derivative[2,0][u][x,y]+μ*Derivative[1,1][v][x,y]-β^2*u[x,y]==0,
         Derivative[0,2][v][x,y]+μ*Derivative[1,1][u][x,y]-β^2*v[x,y]==0,
         u[0,y]==0,v[x,0]==0,
         Derivative[0,1][u][0,y]+Derivative[1,0][v][0,y]==0,
         Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]+Derivative[1,0][v][x,0]==0,
         Derivative[1,0][u][l/2,y]+μ*Derivative[0,1][v][l/2,y]-(1+μ)*α*t==0,
         Derivative[0,1][v][x,b/2]+μ*Derivative[1,0][u][x,b/2]-(1+μ)*α*t==0}
NDSolve[func3, {u, v}, {x, 0, l/2}, {y, 0, b/2}]
```

My mathematical model is as follows:
[image]

I have tried to solve the analytical solution using Maple before, and some parameters can be solved by adding ③④⑤⑥ boundary conditions, but after adding ⑦⑧ conditions, there is no solution, I don't know why. After introducing the condition ③④⑤⑥, the resulting expression is simplified as follows:

[image]

The following is Maple's code:

```
f1 := [diff(v(x, y), y, y) + mu*diff(u(x, y), y, x) - beta^2*v(x, y) = 0,
       diff(u(x, y), x, x) + mu*diff(v(x, y), y, x) - beta^2*u(x, y) = 0,
       u(0, y) = 0, v(x, 0) = 0, 
       D[2](u)(0, y) + D[1](v)(0, y) = 0, 
       D[2](u)(x, 0) + D[1](v)(x, 0) = 0]
sov1 := pdsolve(f1)
convert({sov1[1], sov1[2]}, trig):
simplify(%)
```

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time and hope to get help

Comment: 1. Have you read the built-in FEM tutorial related to solid mechanics (the online version is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/StructuralMechanics/SolidMechanics.html))? 2. Since you can read Chinese, have you read this?: http://note.youdao.com/share/?id=abd51087f44c0b6a41ff6022d549dc41&type=note

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll check out the course on solid mechanics.
The second link cannot be opened.

Comment: That should not happen, it's a youdao note (有道云笔记)! Have you turned off your proxy?

Comment: It really can't be opened

Comment: I registered a Youdao cloud account, now can go in, thank you!

Comment: That's just strange, Youdao note doesn't require one to register. Anyway, it's good to know you finally manage to visit the link.

Comment: I noticed that you gave me a FEM tutorial, but what I wanted was an expression similar to difference

Comment: What do you mean by "an expression similar to difference"?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can solve this problem

Comment: That is, I want the answer to the problem to be a concrete expression

Comment: ……你要实在说不清楚就用中文。

Comment: 不好意思，我现在不确定这个问题是否能解，我希望能达到一个具体的表达式

Comment: 1. ……你是想找符号解/解析解？可你问题问的不是数值解吗？2. 大部分偏微分方程本来就没解析解。3. 仔细一看你条件7和条件8怎么还带了正负号（±L/2, ±B/2）的？是不是写错了？

Comment: 我是想得到解析解的，但一直做不到；现在做数值解也一直出问题

Comment: 不好意思，那个正负号是我之前的边界，我忘记修改了

Comment: 那么，请你把问题里的描述改过来。

Comment: The error says `The dependent variable in u^(0,1)[0,y]+v^(1,0)[0,y]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[u^(0,1)[0,y]+v^(1,0)[0,y]==0,x==0.`] needs to be linear`  look up `ref/message/NDSolve/fembdnl`  It says the given Dirichlet boundary condition is nonlinear and this is not supported.

Comment: Is there any way to solve nonlinear boundary conditions

Comment: May be user21 can answer this. I do not know, but it seems from the messages that it can't solve numerical with non-linear Dirichlet.

Comment: @nasser It's not nonlinear… you remember this?:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224812/1871

Comment: @xzczd I forgot all about that (3 years is long time). So it seems to be a NeumannValue vs. Derivative thing. I was just really going by what the error message itself was saying. may be the error message given by NDSolve should be corrected in this case.

Comment: @Nasser, what I probably you do is add an example to the message ref page where I use a Derivative and that produces that message and then comment on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit reluctant to post this because I've answered similar questions so many times. Anyway, this is hard enough for beginners, so let me do a favor.

As mentioned in comment above, most PDE problems don't have symbolic solution, there might be some hope for your system because it's linear, but were I you, I wouldn't devote into searching for a symbolic solution. In this answer I'll simply show a numeric solution based on finite different method (FDM). The advantage of this method compared with the built-in `FiniteElement` method is, the b.c.s involving derivative can be handled in a straightforward manner; the disadvantage is, you need to know a bit about FDM and core language of *Mathematica* to understand the following code.

The function [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) will be used for discretization of the PDE system.

```
l = 26; b = 18;
μ = 0.2; β = 0.0436; α = 1/10^5; t = 20;
{eq, bc} = With[{u = u[x, y], v = v[x, y]}, 
                {{D[u, {x, 2}] + μ D[v, x, y] - β^2 u == 0, 
                  D[v, {y, 2}] + μ D[u, x, y] - β^2 v == 0}, 
                 {u == 0 /. x -> 0, 
                  D[u, y] + D[v, x] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
                  D[u, x] + μ D[v, y] - (1 + μ) α t == 0 /. x -> l/2, 
                  v == 0 /. y -> 0, 
                  D[u, y] + D[v, x] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
                  D[v, y] + μ D[u, x] - (1 + μ) α t == 0 /. y -> b/2}}]

points@x = points@y = 50; domain@x = {0, l/2}; domain[y] = {0, b/2};
(grid@# = Array[# &, points@#, domain@#]) & /@ {x, y};
difforder = 2;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoafunc = pdetoae[{u, v}[x, y], grid /@ {x, y}, difforder];
del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &; delL = Rest;
ae = {delL /@ del@ptoafunc@eq[[1]], del /@ delL@ptoafunc@eq[[2]]};
aebc = {ptoafunc@bc[[{1, 3, 4, 6}]], del /@ ptoafunc@bc[[{2, 5}]]};

vars = Flatten@Outer[#[#2, #3] &, {u, v}, grid[x], grid@y];
{barray, marray} = CoefficientArrays[Flatten@{ae, aebc}, vars];
sollst = LinearSolve[marray, -N@barray];    
{uarray, varray} = ArrayReshape[sollst, {2, points@x, points@y}];
{usol, vsol} = ListInterpolation[#, grid /@ {x, y}] & /@ {uarray, varray};

{Plot3D[usol[x, y], {x, 0, l/2}, {y, 0, b/2}], 
 Plot3D[vsol[x, y], {x, 0, l/2}, {y, 0, b/2}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Adjusting `points` and `difforder` doesn't seem to result in significant change in solution.

If you still feel worried about the correctness of the solution, consider checking the numeric error. For example, error of $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ can be checked with:

```
Plot[Subtract @@ bc[[3]] /. {u -> usol, v -> vsol} // Evaluate, {y, 0, b/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Subtract @@ bc[[6]] /. {u -> usol, v -> vsol} // Evaluate, {x, 0, l/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

As we can see, the error is rather small, and will be even smaller if we use denser grid for equation solving, which suggests the solution is reliable.

Comment: Dear Mr. xzczd, I don't know why the code is wrong with me.Part::take: Cannot be in pdetoae[{u,v}[x,y],{{0,13/49,26/49,39/49,52/49,65/49,78/49,13/7,104/49,117/49,<<40>>},{0,9/49,18/49,27/49,36/49,45/49,54/49,9/7,72/49,81/49,<<40>>}},2][Derivative[u[x,y],{x,2}]+0.2 Derivative[v[x,y],x,y]-0.00190096 u[x,y]==0]to extract the position 2 to -2.

Comment: As mentioned above, the code makes use of `pdetoae`, please find the source code in the link. @RuiQiangKang

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Mr. xzczd, can you calculate 'σx' and 'σy'? I tried to use Matlab to calculate the difference, but the results did not meet the boundary conditions.

Comment: @RuiQiangKang Then there should be something wrong with your Matlab code. Please check my update.

Comment: Received, thank you. I imported the ‘u’ and ‘v’ calculated by you into Matlab for difference calculation 'σx' and 'σy'.

Comment: @RuiQiangKang If you insist on using MATLAB, are you aware of this issue?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/1871

Comment: I didn't know. I first exported the data of ’usol‘ and ‘vsol’ into excel, and then imported excel into Matlab

Comment: '''Plot3D[D[u, x] + \[Mu] D[v, y] - (1 + \[Mu]) \[Alpha] t /. {u -> usol,
     v -> vsol} // Evaluate, {x, 0, l/2}, {y, 0, b/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]''' Is there a problem with writing code like 'σx'

Comment: @RuiQiangKang Since you can read Chinese, check this: https://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=f2cdd9e72b66c73f372296800de7f7f5

Comment: Dear Mr. xzczd, could you help me draw the surface diagram of σx? The link you gave me before is about the content of editing function. I don't know how to calculate σx and σy through the existing data of u and v

Comment: @RuiQiangKang If you understand the linked tutorial, then you should know how to fix your code to plot `σx`. Please read it more carefully.

Comment: 'Plot3D[D[u, x] + \[Mu] D[v, y] - (1 + \[Mu]) \[Alpha] t /. {u -> usol,
     v -> vsol} // Evaluate, {x, 0, l/2}, {y, 0, b/2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]' I wrote this, I can get a picture, but this surface is a plane, this my finite element software calculated the result is inconsistent, I don't know what is wrong

Comment: @RuiQiangKang Read the tutotial again and think about the following: what's the difference between `f` and `f[x]`?

Comment: 'f'是函数值，'f[x]'是函数关系的意思吗？我这里的就是要用'f[x]'吧